# Parse multi-line string up until first line with certain character

Tags: python, string-parsing

I want to parse out all lines from a multi-line string up until the first line which contains an certain character- in this case an opening bracket.

```
s = """Here are the lines 
of text that i want.
The first line with <tags> and everything
after should be stripped."""

s1 = s[:s.find('<')]
s2 = s1[:s.rfind('\n')]

print s2
```

**Result:**

> Here are the lines
>   of text that i want.
>   The first line with

**What I'm looking for:**

> Here are the lines
>   of text that i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
s2 = s1[:s.rfind('\n')]  #This picks up the newline after "everything"
```

to

```
s2 = s1[:s1.rfind('\n')]
```

and it will work.  There might be a better way to do this though...

Comment: oh dumb- that's what i meant to do, thanks (you need rfind for the newline part though- otherwise you'd only get the first line)

Comment: @Yarin -- Yes, you need `rfind` for the newline part -- not the `'<'` part.  (that's what I meant by the *first* `rfind` -- sorry if that wasn't clear -- Edited to make it slightly more explicit).

Comment: @Yarin -- Oops, apparently you had it as `find` all along.  I don't know why I saw `rfind` in both cases.  Sorry. (edited again to remove my useless (and wrong) comment).